# Why can't I use the show segue in xcode 6.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, segue

So I was doing a test for another **swift** project and I wanted to connect a `TableViewController` that had a `NavigationController` embedded in to a regular `ViewController` using a segue between a bar button item and the second `ViewController`. When I control-drag the button to the `ViewController`, I only get the following options:

[image]

From what I understand, I should see a long list of items including show and show detail. Even if I connect them with **push** or any other segue, I can't select show or show detail as the type of segue if I select the segue. What am I doing wrong? I have not made modifications to **ViewController.swift**. Thanks!

Comment: Did you turn off Size Classes? If you do, you only get the choices you show. Those other choices are for adaptive segues which only make sense in the context of size classes.

Comment: That worked. Weird. Could you post this as an answer so I could accept and +1 it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new adaptive segue choices, "show", "show detail", and "present modally", and "popover presentation" are only available if you're using size classes. This makes sense because there's no need for the segue to be adaptive if you're not using size classes.